# Display record older than 3 months in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a SSIS package that will go through the records in one `table(T1)` older than **3 months** (based on `ALERT_TIMESTAMP`) and move them to another `table(T2)`

My query is :

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE (DATEDIFF([month], ALERT_TIMESTAMP, GETDATE()) > 3)
```

`Alert_timestamp` column is in `Datetime` format. eg: `'10/26/2012 12:00:00 AM'`

When I run the query it should display all the records that are older than **3 months**, but it does not.

Comment: can u provide the structure of the tables?

Comment: What is the date format setting ? 
What is the format when you execute select getdate() ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from `table` where `yourfield` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

For days, year see below for example.

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) /*For getting record specific days*/

DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) /*for getting records specific years*/
```

---

For Anand, query

```
BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 6 MONTH ) AND DATE_SUB( CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 3 MONTH ) 
/* For Getting records between last 6 month to last 3 month
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what OP was asking for. Your solution will return all records in the table that are _younger than_ or _exactly_ 3 months old while the question asked for all records _older_ than 3 months. You just need to change `>=` with `<`

Answer (score 2):

What you posted is not MySQL. Assuming you are using MS SQL Server, you should use the `ABS()` function.

```
SELECT   * FROM        T1
WHERE     ABS(DATEDIFF([month], ALERT_TIMESTAMP, GETDATE())) > 3
```