# SQLite query does not work

Tags: android, sqlite

```
select * from allmessages where  timestamp >  DATETIME('NOW' , '-10 DAY' )
```

I am trying to display messages that are posted before 10 days but this is executing whole i.e from 1 year.

Comment: Look At [**My Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13912197/1719246)

here I explained briefly might be help  full for you

Comment: check my answer below. Make sure you store all dates in TimeStamp form ate Like yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ss (2012:12:13:18:52:05).

Comment: If you get my answer has been solved your problem then please click on right sign in my answer below up vote.

Comment: @Kartheek This is professional site you can not remove my answer and give it right to another answer. you can checked I have give the answer on Feb 2013.

Comment: @Kartheek sorry for the down vote. I have gave +1 his answer for accepting again.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

> **Note: This will only work when you store date in TimeStamp in Database.**

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE DATE(column_name) >= DATE('now', '-10 days');
```

For more detail check this one link:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html