# Selecting all rows where date is 1 month and 1 week old or older - MySql/ PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Still learning PHP so my code is most likely done wrong but I can figure out is what I have done wrong in the code below, It should return 1 row but it will return nothing.

I want to select all rows that are 1 month and 1 week or older from todays date and are not NULL.

rdate is stored as date and is in the format of 0000-00-00

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

// gets today date

```
  $today = date("Y-m-d");
```

// Works out 1 month from today.

```
   $old = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today." -1 Months"));
```

// Works out 1 month and 1 week from today.

```
  $oldweek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($old." -1 Weeks"));
```

// this query should select all rows where the rdate is equal or less than whats set in old week and is not equal to the default date.

```
/* Get status details from database */
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM lpfus_status WHERE rdate < '$oldweek' AND !='0000-00-00' ORDER BY rdate DESC";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13912197/1719246 check answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display record older than 3 months in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912035/display-record-older-than-3-months-in-sql)

Comment: softsdev - I will look at doing it that way although I believe it would still return all rows that are 0000-00-00?

Comment: then try to set 30 + 7 = 37 days like in below query `select * from table where 'yourfield' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 37 DAY )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing column here `AND != '0000-00-00'`

Please try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lpfus_status WHERE rdate < '$oldweek' AND rdate != '0000-00-00' ORDER BY rdate DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks vinodadhikary even looking at it for 2 hours now I didn't notice that!